# .NET CLI in Docker container based on Python image

Tags: python, .net, docker

I am creating an application which is a python FastAPI + Celery app. Inside my Python code, I'm using `subprocess.call` to run a `dotnet test` command.

The problem I am having is that `dotnet` is not recognized.

How can I have the dotnet cli installed in this container?

I already tried installing it in the Dockerfile, but this gave me errors which I do not understand.

EDIT:

Code can be found here: https://github.com/it-graduaten/github-webhook-listener

Here is the Celery log:

```
[2023-07-24 13:48:20,373: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
[2023-07-24 13:48:20,375: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-07-24 13:48:21,380: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-07-24 13:48:34,121: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
[2023-07-24 13:48:34,123: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-07-24 13:48:35,129: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-07-24 13:48:35,136: INFO/MainProcess] celery@02fdaa35ed57 ready.
[2023-07-24 13:48:40,442: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
[2023-07-24 13:48:44,453: INFO/MainProcess] Task run_tests_for_student[5ce2ea10-b15b-4c2f-8824-eea316595ebc] received
[2023-07-24 13:48:44,454: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] Running tests for student
[2023-07-24 13:48:44,455: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] redis://redis:6379/0
[2023-07-24 13:48:44,906: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Request: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,212: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Response: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139 200
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,220: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Request: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/assignments
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,662: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Response: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/assignments 200
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,848: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:45 DEBUG: Getting classroom roster..
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,850: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:45 DEBUG: Got classroom roster
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,851: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:45 DEBUG: Creating directory ./student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589..
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,851: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:45 DEBUG: Created directory ./student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589
[2023-07-24 13:48:45,852: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:45 DEBUG: Cloning oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent to ./student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589..
[2023-07-24 13:48:49,561: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:49 DEBUG: Cloned oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent to ./student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589
[2023-07-24 13:48:49,600: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:49 DEBUG: Getting all exercises in assignment group Permanente evaluatie
[2023-07-24 13:48:49,600: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Request: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/assignment_groups
[2023-07-24 13:48:49,703: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Response: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/assignment_groups 200
[2023-07-24 13:48:49,706: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Request: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/assignment_groups/85653/assignments
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,214: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Response: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/assignment_groups/85653/assignments 200
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,374: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found 22 assignments in assignment group Permanente evaluatie
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,374: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.00 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,375: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.01* with due date 2023-07-30 21:59:59+00:00
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,375: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.02* with due date 2023-07-15 21:59:00+00:00
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,375: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.03* with due date 2023-09-29 21:59:00+00:00
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,375: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.04* with due date 2023-09-29 21:59:00+00:00
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,376: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.05* with due date 2023-09-29 21:59:00+00:00
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,376: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.06 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,376: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.07 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,376: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.08 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,377: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.09 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,377: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 01.10 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,377: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.00 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.01* with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.02* with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.03* with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.04* with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,379: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.05* with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,379: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.06 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,379: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.07 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,379: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.08 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,380: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.09 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,380: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found exercise 02.10 with due date None
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,380: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Found 1 exercises to grade
[2023-07-24 13:48:50,380: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:50 DEBUG: Checking out 3a1c38dbf59566a3f06fafe661393c54f1b5a834..
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,264: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:51 DEBUG: Checked out 3a1c38dbf59566a3f06fafe661393c54f1b5a834
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,264: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:51 DEBUG: Copying solution-repo/01/01_01/test to ././student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589/01/01_01/test..
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,356: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:51 DEBUG: Copied solution-repo/01/01_01/test to ././student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589/01/01_01/test
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,357: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:51 DEBUG: Running tests for ././student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589/01/01_01/test..
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,363: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:51 ERROR: Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dotnet test ././student-repos/oefeningen_oop-CoolsBrent-1690206525.848589/01/01_01/test -l:"trx;LogFileName=result.xml" --verbosity="quiet"'
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,363: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] []
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,364: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-15] 2023-07-24 13:48:51 DEBUG: Uploading results for u0142333
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,364: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Request: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/search_users
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,546: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Response: GET https://thomasmore.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10139/search_users 200
[2023-07-24 13:48:51,554: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-15] Task run_tests_for_student[5ce2ea10-b15b-4c2f-8824-eea316595ebc] succeeded in 7.099790636999842s: True
```

Comment: Could you share what errors you get with your solution? And how you implemented your solution?

Comment: "I already tried installing it in the Dockerfile, but this gave me errors which I do not understand."

Please show what you've tried and what errors you're getting.

Comment: See the edit. I added a link to the repo and the Celery log. Error can be found at `2023-07-24 13:48:51,363`